# iOS - UILabel change appearance of a disabled label

Tags: ios, ipad, uilabel

Further to my question yesterday, I am using a view with UILabels, output to an external monitor.

The labels can have text set on them, unless they are disabled. But (obviously) a disabled label has it's text greyed out. Is there anyway to override this behaviour?

The only other thing I can think of doing is to subclass UILabel and have a variable setting it as editable, but would that affect serialization?

Thanks!

Comment: In override what do you want to change ? color of the text ?

Comment: I want a disabled label to look exactly the same as an enabled label, if this is possible?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a label. What behavior do you want to change about the existing label?

Comment: I want a label, when disabled, to not be greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems that behaviour cannot be changed. I simply subclassed the UILabel and added a variable to check if it was editable. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to prevent user interaction with the label, there is a property named userInteractionEnabled that you can set.

Comment: Disabling User interaction stops things like: resizing etc though, right?

Comment: userInteractionEnabled only applied to user who uses the app.  Your programming code has no effect...

Comment: I am aware of that bu, before the view is shown, the user needs to be able to move and resize the label

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible set the color and alpha attribute.

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.6 blue:0.9 alpha:0.5]
//                          set 'alpha' to something between 0-1 ------^^^
```

Comment: Which I have done, but when a label is disabled, the label is subsequently greyed out. I want to change this behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that a UILabel cannot be changed by user interaction. Even if you use normal label it should suffice. Can you explain the reason y you want to use a disabled label ?

Comment: I think that is the functionality of UIlabel. Just use it normally you should be fine. You cannot change the value of UILabel from user interface until you change the value of label in code.

Comment: Sorry, poor explanation. 1. User adds labels on screen and moves etc. 2. Labels are shown on external screen. 3. Thread updates text of labels with new text,leaving disabled labels unchanged.

Comment: So check if label is disabled don't let the update thread work on it.

Comment: done, but if the label is disabled, the text is greyed out. Which I want to stop?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have label with `disabledTextColor`, similar to `highlightedTextColor`, you have to subclass UILabel and make custom text drawing

#### Swift

```swift
final class Label: UILabel {
  var disabledTextColor: UIColor? {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
  }
  
  override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    guard
      let color = disabledTextColor,
      
      !isEnabled,
      
      let font = font,
      let text = text
    else {
      super.drawText(in: rect)
      return
    }
    
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = textAlignment
    
    NSAttributedString(
      string: text,
      attributes: [
        .font: font,
        .paragraphStyle: paragraph.copy() as! NSParagraphStyle,
        .foregroundColor: color
      ]
    )
    .draw(in: rect)
  }
}
```